# Class Cast Exception in Java: cannot be cast

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception

Could anyone tell me what is the error in this code?

```
public class Node<T> {
    private int degree;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] keys ;
    Node<T>[] children;
    Node(int degree) {
        System.out.println(degree);
        this.degree = degree;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Node<T>[] children = (Node<T>[])new Object[degree * 2];
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T[] keys       = (T[])new Object[(degree * 2) - 1];
     }

     public static void main(String[] s) {
        Node<Integer> a = new Node<Integer>(5);
     }
}
```

Basically I want a self referential kind of a thing that an object stores an array of its own objects. I am getting this error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Tree.Node;

Tree is my package name.

Comment: As a general rule... If there's a compile error, you should change your philosophy. Trying to trick the JVM is probably going to crash. If it wasn't going to crash, it wouldn't be a compile error, it would be a warning instead.

Comment: arrays and generics don't get along very well. use ArrayList<T> if you can.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should take note that you are creating local variables called children and keys in your constructor, not initializing your instance variables with the same names. Probably not what you intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make a Typed array. You have to do this:

```
Node<T>[] children = new Node[degree * 2];
```

And deal with the fact that arrays are untyped :(

Comment: This gives a compiler warning though.

Comment: It does give a warning. And it should give a warning because it's something to be concerned about. But there is an important difference between a warning and an error. Warnings say "The compiler noticed something that *could become* a problem" where as errors say "The compiler noticed something that *is* a problem".

Comment: I have selected this as my answer because what I am trying to implement cannot have list as it has to be of fixed size from the start.... Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Instead of arrays for your children and keys, use `List<Node<T>>` and `List<T>` (and `ArrayList` as the implementation). This way you hide away the complexity of the array creation and casting inside the `ArrayList` class. (It uses an `Object[]`, too, but only converts on `get()` and similar methods instead of trying to have a generic array).

Or, since it looks you are creating kind of a map anyways, use a `Map<T, Node<T>>` for your keys and nodes (you have no index-access then, though).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this:

```
Node<T>[] children = (Node<T>[])new Object[degree * 2];
```

Here you are creating an Object array and an Object is not a Node. You should be creating a Node array instead, i.e.

```
Node<T>[] children = new Node[degree * 2];
```

You have this same error twice in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast an Object to a Node:

```
Node<T>[] children = (Node<T>[])new Object[degree * 2];
```

Either you're thinking of it the wrong way: "Any Object could be a Node" when the only thing that is true is "Every Node is an Object", or, you're used to C++ or similar in which you may cast a void pointer to any other pointer.

Furthermore, you **can't have arrays of generic types**. You'll have to for instance create a wrapper type, say. `StringNode extends Node<String>` in order to store them in an array.

This snippet, for instance, compiles just fine:

```
class Node<T> {
}

class StringNode extends Node<String> {
}

public class Test {
    public void method() {
        Node<String>[] children = new StringNode[5];
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot create `new Node<T>[]` - compile error "generic array creation".

Comment: You can write a `(Node<T>[])new Node<?>[]` (with an unchecked cast).